# How to join two tables in HTSQL specific to any columns

Tags: join, htsql

[HTSQL](http://htsql.org/%20%22HTSQL) works when two tables are properly linked with foreign key.

For example:

**school** can be easily joined with **department** if we have properly defined a **foreign key** say `school_code` of **department** table referencing `code` of **school**.

So far I'm not able to find any way to join two tables on some other columns.

Can any one help me how to do this in [HTSQL](http://htsql.org/%20%22HTSQL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tweak.override` extension allows you to define `foreign-keys` in a config file even if they're not present in the database itself.  http://htsql.org/doc/admin/usage.html#extension-reference

```
tweak.override:
  foreign-keys:
    - program(school_code) -> school(code)
    - program(school_code, part_of_code) -> program
```

Comment: Catherine - is there any current community/activity with HTSQL?